# Show with that induction $\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2{^{2k}}=\frac{2^{2n+2}-1}{3}$, for n = 0,1,2...

Tags: induction

Show with that induction that

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2{^{2k}}=\frac{2^{2n+2}-1}{3}$, for n = 0,1,2...

My attempt

**n = 0**

$LHS = n^0 = 1$

$RHS = (2^2 - 1 ) / 3  = 1$

**n = p**

$LHS_{p} = 2^{2(0)}+2^{2(1)}+2^{2(2)}+...+2^{2(p)}$

$RHS_{p} = \frac{2^{2p+2}-1}{3}$

**n = p + 1**

$LHS_{p+1} = 2^{2(0)}+2^{2(1)}+2^{2(2)}+...+2^{2(p)++2^{2(p+1)}$

$RHS_{p+1} = \frac{2^{2(p+1)+2}-1}{3} $

Now i need to show that:

$RHS_{p+1} = RHS_{p}+2^{2(p+1)}$

$RHS_{p+1} = \frac{2^{2p+2}-1}{3} +2^{2(p+1)}$

Anyone see how i can rewrite?

$\frac{2^{2(p+1)+2}-1}{3} $ to be equal to

$\frac{2^{2p+2}-1}{3} +2^{2(p+1)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{2^{2(p+1)+2}-1}{3}=\frac{4(2^{2(p+1)})-1}{3}=\frac{2^{2(p+1)}-1+3(2^{2(p+1)})}{3}=\frac{2^{2(p+1)}-1}{3}+2^{2(p+1)}$$

Comment: Thanks! :) So easy when you see it...

Comment: Yes that's it thanks.